# Alfresco - Hide title component but Alfresco logo still remains

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Referring to Alfresco wiki and this article:
http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2011/07/27/how-to-hide-content-on-an-existing-alfresco-share-page/

I would remove the title component from the document's detail page. Here is my code:

```
<extension>
   <modules>
      <module>
         <id>Test - Document Details Page</id>
         <evaluator type="default.extensibility.evaluator" />
         <components>
            <component>
               <scope>template</scope>
               <region-id>title</region-id>
               <source-id>document-details</source-id>
               <sub-components>
                  <sub-component id="default">
                     <evaluations>
                        <evaluation id="guaranteedToHide">
                           <render>false</render>
                        </evaluation>
                     </evaluations>
                  </sub-component>
               </sub-components>
            </component>
         </components>
      </module>
   </modules>
</extension>
```

This code seems to work removing the title, but the Alfresco logo still remains...
Attached you will find a screenshot that explain how Alfresco now appears.
Have i modify the FTL of the title component to remove the Alfresco logo? Which FTL?!
[image: Result after removing the title component]

Answer (score 0):

The logo sits in the region-id header and not title :)

take a look at **global.header.xml** and **header.get.html.ftl**